# HTML page not loading for ADO pull request extension

Tags: javascript, html, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-devops-extensions

I've created a ADO extension which shows up in the PR action menu, which adds up in the below menu.
[image: PR extension]

The below is my extension.json

```
{
    "manifestVersion": 1,
    "id": "my-extension-id",
    "publisher": "AlekhyaYalla",
    "version": "1.0.48",
    "name": "PR Extension",
    "description": "Extension for PRs",
    "public": false,
    "categories": ["Azure Repos"],
    "targets": [
        {
            "id": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services"
        }
    ],
    "scopes": [
        "vso.build",
        "vso.code"
    ],
    "contributions": [
        {
            "id": "contribution-id",
            "type": "ms.vss-web.action",
            "targets": [
                "ms.vss-code-web.pull-request-action-menu"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "text": "Create on PR",
                "registeredObjectId": "registerd_id",
                "uri": "dist/PRAction/PRAction.html",
                "iconName": "PC1",
                "name": "***"
            }
        }
    ],
    "files": [
        {
            "path": "dist",
            "addressable": true
        }
    ]
}
```

However I'm trying I'm unable to load the html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="PRAction.js"
      charset="utf-8"
    ></script>
  <body>
    <div id="root">Hello World</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The body part of html is not loading when I'm clicking on extension. I have tried just simple htmls but still not coming at all. Also no loading symbol on click of extension.

Can someone help me if I'm missing something to get a dialog box or atleast a loading symbol while something running on backend of js.
The js part of the code is executing correctly, I can logs and all the functions I'm triggering inside js file are running fine. Please help me with the frontend loading

Thanks in advance